# How to loop through multiple lines in a python string and convert to integers:

Tags: python

I am attempting to cycle through the following code:

`data = "456432 jfhjsdfjs fhdjsjk 990 fdjsf"
345903 fdsfdfs fsfdsfd 667 fsdfd
456432 sfdsfds fdsfdsfd 778 fdsfds"`

I want to convert the numbers of the first series of numbers of each line so it returns the following (converted to integers)

Here is the code I have so far, which sorts everything:

`print [int(data.split()[0])]`

I am guessing I will have to loop through each line while still pulling the 0 item of the list of each line. Though not sure I am on the best workflow for this.

Comment: `[int(row.split()[0]) for row in data.split('\n')]` is one way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate line by line, and then do `split()[0]` to get the first value:

```
[int(line.split()[0]) for line in data.splitlines()]
```

Comment: oh gosh, I've been on code golf too much, i almost commented saying "-1 byte if you remove the whitespace before `for`"

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
y = [int(x) for x in data.split() if x.isdigit() and int(x) > 99999]
y.sort()
```

will return a list of ALL numbers in that string as ints that consist of 6 digits

edit: not return, but rather y will be assigned, and then sorted =D
so really, y will be a list of all integers in that string which consist of 6 digits

Comment: for d in data.split('\n'):

Comment: OP wants the first number in each string and turned into a number

Answer (score 0):

Another short solution to get the number at the beginning of each line by using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) function (from `re` module) with [re.MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag:

```
import re

# your 'data' with text

print(re.findall(r'^\d+\b', data, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

The output:

```
['456432', '345903', '456432']
```